# Run start service when application starts and run across multiple activities

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-service

I want to write an android service that will run with an app.  I want to run this service across multiple activities and have the ability to pass information back to the UI with all activities, not just the activity that starts the service.

From what I understand, I have call `startService` and not bind it to the activity. Is this correct?

Also, I do not want to start a new instance of the service, I want to use the same instance. If i call `startService` in each activity, will that use the same, running instance of the service?

Comment: Why do you think that you need this service?

Comment: Because this has to run in the background and I don't know if I start a new thread in one activity if I can keep it running across to another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startService` will start the service only if there's not a previous service running, it won't spawn a second service.

Once you start your service, you can connect to it from any Activity you want, but to pass information back and forth, you need to *bind* to the service, so you can obtain a pointer to it.

Make sure to read Android's documentation, because the way services work is a little confusing at the beginning.